# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 Java 1.7, tomcat 7

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, tomcat, jdbc

simple connection to DB is fine (mssql,mysql)

but using driver doesn't work

build by java7 tomcat 7

it works well java 8 tomcat 9 in eclipse , spring boot

i tired re-install eclipse ,java ,tomcat

idk what's problem. i checked facet, properties , project properties, build path

added right version of sqljdbc connector, tired 6.0, 6.2.2 ,4.0

also working well with java 8

```
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Mon Nov 25 16:42:11 KST 2019]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/annotation/ManagedBean : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class javax.annotation.ManagedBean)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)








Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javax/annotation/ManagedBean : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class javax.annotation.ManagedBean)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3255)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1420)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1924)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1798)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.registerDefaultFilters(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:201)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.<init>(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:104)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.<init>(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.<init>(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:112)
```

Comment: Seems you're using `javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api` version 1.3.x, which is Java 8+. Downgrade to version 1.2, which is Java 6+.

Answer (score 0):

The version number shown describes the version of the JRE the class file is compatible with.

The reported major numbers are:

```
Java SE 13 = 57,
Java SE 12 = 56,
Java SE 11 = 55,
Java SE 10 = 54,
Java SE 9 = 53,
Java SE 8 = 52,
Java SE 7 = 51,
Java SE 6.0 = 50,
Java SE 5.0 = 49,
JDK 1.4 = 48,
JDK 1.3 = 47,
JDK 1.2 = 46,
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

Compile it in same version and run it on same version